# Boolean not working and I've tried every fix I could find online

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, boolean-modifier

so I've been using Blender recently, but every single model I try to work on, I get this weird issue where the bool tools and the modifier just doesn't do what it's supposed to, sometimes it just deletes random models, sometimes it makes cuts in a model but doesn't actually go through with the bool and reconstruction of the mesh, no matter what I do, if I follow tutorials or do new projects, I just keep getting this issue. The only way I can bool is if I just do it with a fresh object with no modifications to it, like any extrusions or subdivisions.

I've tried re-calculating the normals on both objects, I've tried merging the vertices by distance, I checked for non-manifold edges, I can't find any other fixes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Fast option seems to work

Comment: Yep. Fine with the Fast option here too.

Comment: Fast option isn't working for me though, could it be my Blender version that has a bugged boolean or something?